# How to update the schema of a Spark DataFrame (methods like Dataset.withColumn and Datset.select don't work in my case)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe

My question is if there are any approaches to update the schema of a DataFrame without explicitly calling `SparkSession.createDataFrame(dataframe.rdd, newSchema)`.

Details are as follows.

I have an original Spark DataFrame with schema below:

```
root
 |-- column11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column13: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column14: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column15: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column16: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column17: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column18: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column19: string (nullable = true)
```

I applied `Dataset.mapPartitions` on the original DataFrame and got a new DataFrame (returned by `Dataset.mapPartitions`).
The reason for using `Dataset.mapPartitions` but not `Dataset.map` is better transformation speed.

In this new DataFrame, every row should have a schema like below:

```
root
 |-- column21: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column22: long (nullable = true)
 |-- column23: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column24: long (nullable = true)
 |-- column25: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column251: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column252: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column253: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column254: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column255: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- column256: string (nullable = true)
```

So the schema of the new DataFrame should be the same as the above.

However, the schema of the new DataFrame won't be updated automatically. The output of applying `Dataset.printSchema` method on the new DataFrame is still original:

```
root
 |-- column11: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column12: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column13: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column14: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column15: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column16: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column17: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column18: string (nullable = true)
 |-- column19: string (nullable = true)
```

So, in order to get the correct (updated) schema, what I'm doing is using `SparkSession.createDataFrame(newDataFrame.rdd, newSchema)`.
My concern here is that falling back to RDD (`newDataFrame.rdd`) will hurt the transformation speed because Spark Catalyst doesn't handle RDD as well as Dataset/DataFrame.

My question is if there are any approaches to update the schema of the new DataFrame without explicitly calling `SparkSession.createDataFrame(newDataFrame.rdd, newSchema)`.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: You seem to have some code which "doesn't work". Unless you share your code (a.k.a [mcve] or [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48427185)) it is almost impossible to diagnose and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use RowEncoder to define schema for newDataFrame.
See following example.

```
val originalDF = spark.sparkContext.parallelize(List(("Tonny", "city1"), ("Rogger", "city2"), ("Michal", "city3"))).toDF("name", "city")
val r = scala.util.Random
val encoderForNewDF = RowEncoder(StructType(Array(
  StructField("name", StringType),
  StructField("num", IntegerType),
  StructField("city", StringType)
)))
val newDF = originalDF.mapPartitions { partition =>
  partition.map{ row =>
    val name = row.getAs[String]("name")
    val city = row.getAs[String]("city")
    val num = r.nextInt
    Row.fromSeq(Array[Any](name, num, city))
  }
} (encoderForNewDF)

newDF.printSchema()  
|-- name: string (nullable = true)  
|-- num: integer (nullable = true)  
|-- city: string (nullable = true)
```

Row Encoder for spark: https://jaceklaskowski.gitbooks.io/mastering-spark-sql/spark-sql-RowEncoder.html